# How to install angular-ui-bootstrap via npm in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to install angular-ui-bootstrap in the following steps:
1. `npm install angular-ui-bootstrap`
2. `import uiBootstrap from 'angular-ui-bootstrap';`
3. `angular.module ('app', [
     uiBootstrap
   ])`

I want to add:

```
<pager total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" items-per- 
page="itemsPerPage"></pager>
```

In the package.json file, I do not see any dependencies named `angular-ui-bootstrap`

Comment: npm install -s angular-ui-bootstrap . the -s flag will add the dependency to your package.json.
What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I don' t have any errors. Your solution doesn't work. I can't see this in package.jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this:

`npm install angular-ui-bootstrap --save`.

The flag `--save` should add the dependency to package.json file.

Also, you will need to add the link to the CSS file path into the `index.html` to load the CSS.

Comment: It saved in package.json, but I can't add `<pager total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" items-per- page="itemsPerPage"></pager>`

Comment: Do you want to display the pager?
This is something from the documentation.
`<div>
    <h4>Pager</h4>
    <pre>You are currently on page {{currentPage}}</pre>
    <ul uib-pager total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"></ul>
</div>`

Comment: Yes. I found it in the documentation - pagination

Comment: I can't see on the page.

Comment: Please share the code, so that we can figure out the issue.

Comment: It looks like it does not load angular-ui-bootstrap

Comment: How to check if the application detects it?

Comment: Check into the 'Network' tab of 'Developers tools' on the browser. 
Check the files for the bootstraps are loaded. Generally, they are named something like this: bootstrap.min.css, ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js

Comment: does not load css bootstrap

Comment: Check to see if you have provided the path for JS and css files. Generally, it is given in index.html file `script` tag.

Comment: In app.js added import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; it's correct path; when I      put link to bootstrapp css in index.html it's work. How import bootstrap css via import  in app.js?

Comment: You will need to keep both. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193341/discussion-between-umbro-and-harshad).